# Spring Boot Elastic Search Client with ReactiveElasticsearchOperations

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

**Given:**
I'm attempting to develop a new spring boot application that uses elastic search. After reviewing the official Spring Boot documentation, I chose to use **ReactiveElasticsearchOperations** for all interactions in the Spring Boot application.
However, while testing the code read flow, it works flawlessly, but all write-related activities fail with the status code: 500, Internal Server Error. However, when I check my elastic search, I see that the necessary indexes and data have been created.

Could you please advise on how to resolve this problem?

[The source codes are all available in the Git repo linked below](https://github.com/GRajaMca/spring-reactive-elastic-search-client)

**Error Message**

```
2023-07-13 16:48:18.531  INFO 8445 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-07-13 16:48:19.035  INFO 8445 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8338
2023-07-13 16:48:19.044  INFO 8445 --- [           main] ngReactiveElasticSearchClientApplication : Started SpringReactiveElasticSearchClientApplication in 1.337 seconds (JVM running for 1.939)
2023-07-13 16:48:32.200 ERROR 8445 --- [r-http-kqueue-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [71938b39-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/reactive"

org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: {"_index":"user","_id":"1as","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":0,"_primary_term":1}
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.doDecode(DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.java:762) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler io.javabeans.springreactiveelasticsearchclient.controller.ReactiveElasticSearchController#saveUser(User) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/reactive" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.doDecode(DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.java:762) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.lambda$readResponseBody$24(DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.java:738) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.24.jar:3.4.24]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:702) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.24.jar:1.0.24]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) ~[netty-handler-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:336) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:308) ~[netty-codec-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueStreamChannel$KQueueStreamUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueStreamChannel.java:544) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueChannel.java:383) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.processReady(KQueueEventLoop.java:213) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:291) ~[netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.84.Final.jar:4.1.84.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```